# Trying to create a button that splits into two new buttons on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am super stuck creating this type of button effect.  I want to make my main button "split" into two new buttons on click.  I put together my best attempt on codepen here http://codepen.io/bananahavana/pen/LbpRqp (don't laugh!)

```js
$('.button1').click(function() {
  $('.button1').addClass('clicked');
  $('.reveal').addClass('opened');
});
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
}
a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #cc0066;
  padding: 1rem 2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.clicked {
  width: 0;
  padding: 1rem 0rem;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.button2,
.button3 {
  width: 0;
  padding: 1rem 0rem;
}
.opened {
  width: 80px;
  padding: 1rem 2em;
  height: 18px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.button2 {
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.button3 {
  left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a class="button1" href="#">Button1</a>
  <a class="reveal button2" href="#">Button 2</a>
  <a class="reveal button3" href="#">Button 3</a> 
</div>
```

I'd really appreciate some insight on:

- What this type of button animation this is called, if it has a name.
- Advice on how to accomplish it.

Thanks!!

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? It seems to work in creating two buttons when you click the first one

Comment: yes , it is working . What specific issue are you facing with that?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your responses. It is working but the animation looks funky in my opinion. I'd like to somehow make the following happen: A) make the two ````.reveal```` buttons expand from the center of the container (where the first button disappeared into).     B) Have the two ````.reveal```` buttons grow in width from their *outer edge* only.     C) Have the two ````.reveal```` buttons then slide out toward the edges of the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that effect with the CSS3 `tranform:translate` and `transition`.
I hope that is what you wish. If you have any further questions, please ask.
[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/5r01sh5d/) is a fiddle to this code.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#button1').on('click',function(){
   $('#button2').addClass('animateToRight');
            $('#button3').addClass('animateToLeft');
            $('#button1').addClass('hide');
  });
 });
```

```css
.hide{
  opacity:0;
}

#button3, #button2{
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: transform 2s;
}
#button1{
  z-index:10;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari */
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.animateToRight{
  -webkit-transform: translate(100px); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(100px);
}
.animateToLeft{
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100px); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(-100px);
}

button{
    background-color: green;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -50px;
 margin-left: -50px;
}
.blobs {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: white;
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blobs">
<button id="button2">YYY</button>
<button id="button1">XXX</button>
<button id="button3">ZZZ</button>
</div>
```